# Rails+Devise "Reset password token is invalid"—but the token matches the db token...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Trying to reset a password, my (custom) mailer has this line:

```
edit_user_password_url(@user, reset_password_token: @user.reset_password_token)
```

And that creates a link like this:

```
http://fixit-rails.dev//users/password/edit.6?reset_password_token=13f76244d39b0dfb9746674058a45559280358b99c1fdc36c6b9af2de2ba6376
```

And within the database the user has the following `reset_password_token`:

```
13f76244d39b0dfb9746674058a45559280358b99c1fdc36c6b9af2de2ba6376
```

The user can successfully go to the new password screen, but when he clicks submit, an error message says `"Reset password token is invalid"`

Why is devise not recognising the token?

**UPDATE**

I create the token with the following code:

```
def generate_reset_password_token
    raw, enc = Devise.token_generator.generate(User, :reset_password_token)
    self.reset_password_token   = enc
    self.reset_password_sent_at = Time.now.utc
    self.save(validate: false)
end
```

Comment: In your email template it should be the @token not @user.reset_password_token. like : `edit_user_password_url(@user, reset_password_token: @token)`

Comment: @token doesn't exist, how do I create it? Please note I'm in a custom mailer, not one of the Devise ones.

Comment: Can you share the code where you are setting the token in controller and sending reset password email if possible ?

Comment: I can, but after the weekend—it's easter! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

```
edit_user_password_url(@user, reset_password_token: @user.reset_password_token)
```

Should instead be:

```
edit_user_password_url(@user, reset_password_token: @token)
```

What is `@token`, you may ask? it's the `raw` from:

```
def generate_reset_password_token
    raw, enc = Devise.token_generator.generate(User, :reset_password_token)
    self.reset_password_token   = enc
    self.reset_password_sent_at = Time.now.utc
    self.save(validate: false)
end
```

In Devise it's set automagically, but if you are doing your own thing, you need to save `raw` and set `@token` to `raw` in your mailer.